# Fetching variables from database

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

http://www.srcf.ucam.org/~sas98/ents/index.php

I have a table called `ents` with a varchar(100) field called `week` containing the value 'Easter Term 2011, Week 1'. However, the output returns 'Array'.

My code is:

```
function printWeek() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT week FROM ents") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($week = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        echo "$week";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When a variable prints "Array" when you're expecting a string, the first debugging step is `print_r( $week );`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `mysql_fetch_array` which returns... wait for it... an **array**.  You need to access the first element of the array if you want an actual value:

```
echo $week[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches array of row data (as the name hints), so you have to threat is as such:

```
function printWeek() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT week FROM ents") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($ents = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        echo $ents[0];
    }
}
```